# Controller generated <ul> and <li> tags loading as literal text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Am using the following code to create a menu structure as part of my MVC4 application:

```
    public string loadTabStructure(int lvl, int pId)
    {
        string tabsStr = "";
        DataView lvlTabs = null;
        lvlTabs = dtTabs.AsDataView();
        string strFilter = "";
        if (lvl == 0)
        {
            strFilter = "Level = " + lvl;
        }
        else
        {
            strFilter = "Level = " + lvl + " AND ParentId = " + pId;
        }
        if (strFilter.Length > 0)
        {
            lvlTabs.RowFilter = strFilter;
        }
        DataTable dtLvl = lvlTabs.ToTable();
        if (dtLvl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tabsStr += "<ul>";
            foreach (DataRow row in dtLvl.Rows)
            {
                tabsStr += "<li>" + row.Field<string>("TabName");
                tabsStr += loadTabStructure(lvl + 1, row.Field<int>("TabID"));
                tabsStr += "</li>";
            }
            tabsStr += "</ul>";
        }
        return tabsStr;
    }
```

Problem is run it runs it displays the <ul> and <li> tags as text rather than rendering them as html tags.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

loadRabStructure is put in ViewBag.TabStructure
View looks like so

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pages";
}

<h2>Pages</h2>

@ViewBag.TabStructure
```

Comment: How does your view look like ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pages";
}

<h2>Pages</h2>

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.TabStructure)
```